# Other apps interfacing with Flask

Tags: flask, flask-socketio

The title may be wrong but hoping to explain it (a bit) better. I have a Flask app serving a website. I have another app that recognises hand gestures based on a trained model. How can I have the hands gestures trigger an event in the flask app eg browse to another page on the website. 
I was thinking of using flask-socketio to create a websocket that the two apps could communicate through...I was also thinking of running the hand gesture app as a thread in the flask app and also use a websocket... Any help on this would be much appreciated. 
I've often wondered how I would get other apps/threads to interface with flask so also curious what people have done to accomplish this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1st Solution**:

If both are Flask app or just Web app, then you can just use the Requests library as explained [here](https://2.python-requests.org//en/master/).
It is the easiest way.

Example of possible setup:

- The 1st app is listening on localhost:**5000**
- The 2nd app is listening on localhost:**5001**

The 1st app finished a job, then it executes the following line:

```py
r = requests.get('http://localhost:5001/finished_job')
```

And in your 2nd app:

```py
@application.route("/finished_job", methods=["GET"])
def finished_job():
    """Do what you have to do."""
```

It is called REST API. Apps communicate via HTTP requests. That is the easier you can do.

**2nd Solution:**
Communication between processes using Queue as explained [here](https://pymotw.com/2/multiprocessing/communication.html)

**3rd Solution:**
Writing results into a file and read the file in your Flask app.

**4th Solution:**
Import your first app, in your flask app. And make it run into a thread. Or call it only when you need.

Comment: Reese, the hand gestures app is just a standalone python app (not a flask app)... It currently runs a while True loop and uses a capture from opencv and outputs a letter based on the hand gesture.... But again this is just an example of a larger question I'm trying to understand. How do you get other (non flask) apps to interface with flask. As an FYI, I got this working by bringing the code from the hand gesture app into flask and running it as a background thread and using socketio (flask-socketio and JS socketio).... Just trying to see if there is a better, more efficient way to do it.

Comment: @Lazypaddy see the edit. I'm trying to find a solution that could be useful for you.

Comment: Thanks a million for the answers....No real right or wrong answer on this one I think, but accepting as solution because it gives a good range of options. What I did in the end is the following sudo code: